# Probability of drawing $n$ balls with two kinds of color

Tags: probability

A bag contains a red ball, a blue ball and a green ball. Draw a ball with replacement $n$ times. What is the probability of $n$ results with exactly two colors are drawn?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Do you mean exactly two colors are drawn or at least two colors are drawn?  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

The probability that only $2$ particular colours are drawn is $\left(\frac23\right)^n$. There are $\binom32=3$ pairs of colours, but if we add their probabilities, we’ve included two counts for each case where only one colour is drawn, so we have to subtract those twice, yielding $3\left(\frac23\right)^n-6\left(\frac13\right)^n$. (This is correct for $n\gt0$; for $n=0$ we’d also have to take into account the case where $0$ colours are drawn.)